# int or index when doing numbering list for C++ maps

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the `map` to arrange my output, which is a password generated from the name and ic number, for each of the students. I wanted the output to be arranged in a numbering list. After I searched online, I found that it can be done using index or int. The class I'm taking is about Data Structures and it leans heavily towards how efficient the program can be. I've already managed to get the output I want but I want to ask which way is more efficient or the better way to do it. Sorry if you don't understand what I'm saying, my explanation skills are quite terrible. If there's any improvement that can be made do let me know. TQVM.

By int:

```
 void displayStudent(map<string, string>& studentMap) {
    map<string, string>::iterator displayStudentAndPassword = studentMap.begin();
    int i = 1;
    for (displayStudentAndPassword = studentMap.begin(); displayStudentAndPassword != studentMap.end(); displayStudentAndPassword++) {
        cout << i << ". " << displayStudentAndPassword->first << ":- " << displayStudentAndPassword->second << endl;
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

By index:

```
void displayStudent(map<string, string>& studentMap) {
    map<string, string>::iterator displayStudentAndPassword = studentMap.begin();
    int index = 1;
    for (displayStudentAndPassword = studentMap.begin(); displayStudentAndPassword != studentMap.end(); displayStudentAndPassword++) {
        cout << index << ". " << displayStudentAndPassword->first << ":- " << displayStudentAndPassword->second << endl;
        cout << endl;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Output Image

[image]

Comment: 2 things. 1. Dont put the image link in your question, actually copy the output text and put it here. 2. What do you expect the difference to be between your code blocks, as far as i can tell the only difference is the name of the index/i variable, which means nothing in terms of functional difference.

Comment: "Efficient" in terms of what?  Code size?  Memory size?  Memory layout?  Instruction count?  Scalability?  Compilation speed?  Execution time?  Readability?  Maintainability?  There are always tradeoffs.  If you care about speed, in this case the cost of incrementing an integer is far less than traversing a binary search tree which will periodically miss L1 cache, and this in turn is far less expensive than writing stuff to standard out, and then invoking a stream flush via the use of `std::endl` will be worse again.  So, yeah it's absolutely fine, practically unmeasurable to count items.

Comment: Your `index` or `i` should be `std::size_t` (or even better, `std::map::size_type`) because if your map has more elements than `int`, then your index will overflow unpredictably.

Comment: You might use for range, instead of iterators. `std::size_t i = 1; for (const auto& p : studentMap) { std::cout << i << ". " << p.first << ":- " << p.second << std::endl; ++i }`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the two solutions are identical. The only difference is that you have named your variable for tracking the index number differently. You named it "i" in one "index" in another. In this case you aren't using it as an index. You're just numbering your output. By using a map, there is no index number. Instead you have a key which is the first string in std::map<string, string>.

Maps are great for quickly mapping from one object to another. In this case from one string to another. Presumably so you can map from a student name to their stored password. However, if your code elsewhere doesn't need this, then I suggest using a vector instead of a map. Since it is fundamentally an array of objects referenced by index. Of course the object contained in the vector would then have to be an class or structure to hold both values, the name and password.